# Mobile form placeholders' text color doesn't change

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have created a form for my website, and it has a desktop version and a mobile one. For some reason, it ignores my color property and the text looks light grey on mobile instead of the color I have picked.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/?preview_nonce=b596cad62f#wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2" method="post" class="wpcf7-form cf7-style" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="1224">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.0.2">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="6">
</div>
<p><label>     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder=":שם*"></span> </label></p>
<p><label>     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap company-name"><input type="text" name="company-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder=":שם חברה"></span> </label></p>
<p><label>     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel-888"><input type="tel" name="tel-888" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel tel-888" id="tel-888" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder=":טלפון*"></span> </label></p>
<p><label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-777"><input type="email" name="email-777" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-email email-777" id="email-777" aria-invalid="false" placeholder=":אימייל"></span></label></p>
<p><label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="textarea-20" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder=":הודעה"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<div align="left"><label> <input type="submit" value="שלח" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit button-20" id="button-20"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></label></div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/* webkit solution */
input[type='text'] { text-align:right;


}
/* mozilla solution */
input:-moz-placeholder { text-align:right; }


input[type='text'], input[type='tel'], input[type="email"]{
text-align:right;
font-family: heebo;
    color: #001a71 !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;border: 1px solid #001a71 !important;
font-size: 1.563em !important;
height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -30px !important;
    margin-top: -28px !important;
    position: static !important
    min-width: 190px;

}
@media screen and (min-width: 415px) {
    textarea {
    height: 190px;
text-align:right;
font-family: heebo;
    color: #001a71 !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;border: 1px solid #001a71 !important;
font-size: 1.563em !important;
    margin-top: -4px
    !important;
    margin: 0 -10px;
        position: static !important
        min-width: 190px;



}
#button-22 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #4a5ba8;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4a5ba8;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
            transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
            padding: 10px;
            margin:0 -103%;
                position: relative;
                min-width:43.446 px
                max-width: 43.446px ;!important
}

.contact-form-wrapper input[type=”submit”]
            float: left !important;
}

#button-22:hover {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #4a5ba8;

    border: 1px solid #4a5ba8;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
            transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
            padding: 10px;
                            position: relative
                min-width:43.446 px
                max-width: 43.446px
            float: !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 416px) {
span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
visibility: hidden
}

.cf7-style div.wpcf7-validation-errors {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #001a71 !IMPORTANT;
    border: none !important;
        min-width: 200px;
              font-family: Heebo;
              margin-top: -30px;
        margin-top: -30px;

}
body .cf7-style div.wpcf7-response-output
{
padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
.wpcf7-response-output
{
      margin: 0;
    padding: -1pX -1PX -1PX;
    HEIGHT: 28PX;
    TEXT-ALIGN: CENTER;
          font-family: Heebo;
          font-size: 1.3em;
                min-width: 180px;
            margin-top: -30px;


}

body .cf7-style input[type=”text”]:focus,
body .cf7-style input[type=”email”]:focus,
body .cf7-style textarea:focus {
      min-width: 180px;
      color: #001a71;
                font-size: 1.3em;


}
[placeholder]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #001a71 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  left: auto;
  color: #001a71 !important;
  min-width: 164px;
}

[placeholder]:focus {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease !important;
  min-width: 164px;
}


[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
      color: #001a71 !important;

}}
```

Can anyone tell me please, why the color of the text inside the placeholders is light grey on mobile display? You can also see the form at the bottom of this website: [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is slightly messy, I don't know what color you want on smaller screens, but you can change it using this

```
#wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2 ::placeholder {
     color: #001a71; /* <-- blue color */
}
```

And then wrap it in like you have done so far

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2 ::placeholder {
        color: #001a71;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4eo5rztw/8/)

Comment: Yes! Thanks, it worked. :-) Code is messy because I actually used a live builder, but I have attached the HTML code to respect the community's rules. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting something like this, check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp) for more info.

```
    #wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2 ::placeholder {
        color: red;
        opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
    }

    #wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2 :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
       color: red;
    }

    #wpcf7-f1224-p6-o2 ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
       color: red;
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you or not.